# Send e-mail notification from jenkins when warning occurs in ms-build

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using **jenkins** as my CI server for my .Net based project. I am using **MS-Build** plugin to build project from jenkins. It is working as expected, it sends an email when build gets failed. Now I also want jenkins to send email when build has warning in it. I could not find any plugin which provides this functionality out of box.

So I tried to use "*Extended Email Notification*", "*Console Output Parsing*" plugins. But it does not give me expected behaviour. Currently what I have acheived is sending a mail when warning occured. I mark build as unstable using "Console output parsing" plugin and send email using e-mail notification. But e-mail does not have details about warnings.

I came across few articles where it says we can use *groovy script* or *jelly script* and "*Extended Email Notification*" plugin to send details. But I don't how to fetch details of warning from *parsing plugin*. Can someone point me to correct resources or guide me to acheive this?

Answer (score 3):

Look for

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin mark Build as "unstable" by parsing of log files. You can run downstream Jobs(if you have) also after "unstable" builds --> see job config. Status "unstable" is the "gray area" in Jenkins but has yellow color.
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin sends E-Mails also for "unstable" builds with text extracted from build log files.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins is based on the assumption that a specific build (or "run") can either be "good" or "bad", hence the two-color scheme - there is no "gray area" for that matter.

Having said that, there are plugins to allow for a third state of "unstable",
which is also supported by the triggering mechanism.

Take for example the **[Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)** or the **[Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin)** - 
both will allow you to search keywords in files you specify and use that to downgrade a 'successful' build 
to 'unstable' or a 'failed'.